# Return custom response after post request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am logging a user in the system by sending data through a FormData() to the action in the backend. The user logs in, everything is fine. I want to send back to the frontend a response (string, Json) doesn't matter.

```
    [Route("login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

        var result = await mSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return new JsonResult("Succeeded", new JsonSerializerSettings());
            // or return new[] { user.DisplayName, user.Role };
        }

        return new JsonResult("Failed", new JsonSerializerSettings());
    }
```

On the frontend I expect to see the passed string or json, but I get this as a response from fetch.

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "https://ip/api/sampledata/login", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "https://ip/api/sampledata/login"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the [`ContentResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult.aspx) to return a plain string:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

    var result = await mSignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, true, false);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return new JsonResult("Succeeded", new JsonSerializerSettings());
        // or return new[] { user.DisplayName, user.Role };
    }

    return Content("Failed");
}
```

[`ContentResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult.aspx) by default returns a `text/plain` as its *contentType*.

Comment: I have updated my answer, because I think my problem is at the front-end. Because I did what you answered and it was the same